# error identification (IndentationError: expected an indented block)

Tags: python

```
x= int (input("Enter a number : "))
if x>1:
 for f in range (2,x):
 if (x%f)==0:
 print (x, "is not a prime number ")
 print (f,"times",x//f,"is",x)
 break
 
 else :
 print (x, "is a prime number ")
else:
 print (x,"is not a prime ")
```

it says

```
    if (x%f) ==0:
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

im hoping to solve it

Comment: search and read something about `python indentation´

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: Indentation is crucial in Python. If you don't know what it is used for, then please reread the tutorial. If you know what it's for, then answer yourself the question: "What is the body of the for loop `for f in range (2,x):`?"

Answer (score -1):

just press the tab key in the starting of the line in which it is showing error it might help you with indentation error as it's not inside the for loop it's somewhere outside the for loop that's why it's showing error while running